# How to make a page slides into a subchapter after clicked

Tags: text, onclick, slide

please, I'm writing a very long text (chapters) and I would like to make an index, example :

A chapters - B  chapters  - C ...  when make click on (A)...page slides down up to (A chapters ) area

Please, how make this, and how is called this technique for future use not forget.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the element you're sliding to an indiovidual id like "chapter1"

```
<div id="chapter1">
    ONCE upon a time, blablabla
</div>
```

and an anchor targeting to this div

```
<a href="#chapter1">
       Chapter1
</a>
```

Your can simply access to this chapterwith a link using it like so :

http:/yourwebsite/yourtext.html#chapter1

Comment: ooh,.yes its work...just there can be no space ..thanks alot :)